# odeint behaves differently when changing the t interval

Tags: python, plot, ode, odeint

I have this system of equations:

```
def Diffeq(v,t, lam, gam,a):
    c=[i for i in range(0,len(v))]
    vdot = np.empty_like(v) 

    for i in range(0,len(v)):
        if i == 0:
            vdot[0] = gam*c[1]*v[1]
        elif i == (len(v)-1):
            vdot[i] =  lam*a[i-1]*v[i-1] - (lam*a[i]+gam*c[i])*v[i]
        else:
            vdot[i]=  lam*a[i-1]*v[i-1] - (lam*a[i]+gam*c[i])*v[i]+ 
                                                     gam*c[i+1]*v[i+1]
    return vdot
```

where lambda, gamma and a are the following set of parameters (N=1000):

```
a = [6*i*(N-i)/(N-1.0) for i in range (0,N+1)]
gamma = 1
lam = 2
```

if I call:

```
t = np.linspace(0,3,100)
incond=np.array([0.0]*(N+1) #from 0 to 1000 included
incond[i0] =1.0 
y = odeint(Diffeq, incond, t, args=(lam,gamma,a))
```

and I try to plot the expected value of my y:

```
finalv = np.array([0.0]*100)
for time in range(0,100):
    for k in range(0,N+1):
        finalv[time] = finalv[time] + (k)*y[time][k]
```

I can plot the results and I have a nice, expected curve:
[image]

If I want to change my t interval, to

```
t = linspace(0,50,100)
```

and I then try to plot, the shape of the curve changes!
[image]

Sometimes, if I play a bit with the values of a, I obtain this runtime warning:

```
/home/myub/Desktop/Odeintegration.py:79: RuntimeWarning: overflow 
encountered in double_scalars
```